# How can I send a response that will delete all applicable cookies named X?

Tags: http, cookies, http-headers

Let's say I'm running a Web application. Let's also say that I started noticing a really large cookie in my web logs—perhaps it was introduced by a third party library, via a hosted service on a subdomain, or via a bug in my code, etc.

The important detail here is that I don't actually know much about the cookie (and since cookies in a request don't give any details about the domain or path they were saved with, I can't easily find out), but I want to have a rule to delete it (either in my application or at some layer in front of my application).

What can I send back to the browser to delete that cookie regardless of the domain, subdomain, path, etc., it was originally set with? Is there any reasonably straightforward way to do it?

Experimenting locally, it seems like the `SET-COOKIE` header to delete a cookie must match both domain and path in order to effectively delete that cookie. But unless there's some way around that, that means there's no way I can delete the cookie other than by trial and error and checking my weblogs. Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 1):

You must provide the same `domain` and `path` attributes that were set on the original cookie. You can't avoid that, they are vital to the cookie storage model:

[HTTP State Management Mechanism](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265)

```
4.1.2.  Semantics (Non-Normative)

   ...

   If the user agent receives a new cookie with the same cookie-name,
   domain-value, and path-value as a cookie that it has already stored,
   the existing cookie is evicted and replaced with the new cookie.
   Notice that servers can delete cookies by sending the user agent a
   new cookie with an Expires attribute with a value in the past.

   ...

5.3.  Storage Model

   ...

   When the user agent "receives a cookie" from a request-uri with name
   cookie-name, value cookie-value, and attributes cookie-attribute-
   list, the user agent MUST process the cookie as follows:

   ...

   11.  If the cookie store contains a cookie with the same name,
        domain, and path as the newly created cookie:

        1.  Let old-cookie be the existing cookie with the same name,
            domain, and path as the newly created cookie.  (Notice that
            this algorithm maintains the invariant that there is at most
            one such cookie.)

        2.  If the newly created cookie was received from a "non-HTTP"
            API and the old-cookie's http-only-flag is set, abort these
            steps and ignore the newly created cookie entirely.

        3.  Update the creation-time of the newly created cookie to
            match the creation-time of the old-cookie.

        4.  Remove the old-cookie from the cookie store.

   12.  Insert the newly created cookie into the cookie store.

   ...
```

> The important detail here is that I don't actually know much about the cookie (and since cookies in a request don't give any details about the domain or path they were saved with, I can't easily find out)

The fact that you are receiving a cookie at all means the URL being requested must match the `domain` and `path` of the original `Set-Cookie`.  So, you can issue a new `Set-Cookie` whose `domain` and `path` attributes match the current URL being requested, at a minimum.  Of course, that will not delete the cookie if it is using a higher `domain` and/or `path` to allow for sub-domains and sub-paths.  You would have to issue additional `Set-Cookie` headers for different combinations of domain/path wildcards that also match the current URL being requested.

For example, if the URL being requested is `http://mysite.myserver.com/path/to/file`, and you want to delete the `somecookie` cookie, you could issue `Set-Cookie` headers like this:

```
Set-Cookie: somecookie=; Domain=mysite.myserver.com; Path=/path/to/; Expires=Sun, 06 Nov 1994 08:49:37 GMT
Set-Cookie: somecookie=; Domain=mysite.myserver.com; Path=/path/; Expires=Sun, 06 Nov 1994 08:49:37 GMT
Set-Cookie: somecookie=; Domain=mysite.myserver.com; Path=/; Expires=Sun, 06 Nov 1994 08:49:37 GMT
Set-Cookie: somecookie=; Domain=myserver.com; Path=/path/to/; Expires=Sun, 06 Nov 1994 08:49:37 GMT
Set-Cookie: somecookie=; Domain=myserver.com; Path=/path/; Expires=Sun, 06 Nov 1994 08:49:37 GMT
Set-Cookie: somecookie=; Domain=myserver.com; Path=/; Expires=Sun, 06 Nov 1994 08:49:37 GMT
```

Not a perfect solution, but it is probably about as close as you are going to get without knowing the detail of the original cookie.

Comment: I'm struggling with the same issue and I'm starting to believe there is no way to delete a cookie if you don't know the path, since it can also include the query part, so if your cookie is set for `/path/to/script.php?foo=bar` then you will receive the cookie only when that particular query string is set.
Moreover you should at least add `/path` and `/path/to` since they are also valid for cookies.